# Blend is not working after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Community RTM from Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, blend

Trying to start Blend by using menu View->Design in Blend from IDE. 
Blend successfully started after few freezes and crashes, but appears that there is no any project opened - solution explorer is empty. After this, while trying to close Blend window I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"...
Also tried to start Blend from Start-> Blend for Visual Studio 2015. Doing this I get at least three error messages saying that some of the packages couldn`t be found. Blend started successfully, but while trying to open my project I get a detailed message saying that my project somehow is not compatible with Blend... This is stupid because it was created and maintained in VS 2015RC.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezing and crashing: Got the same issue. Just restarting all the time. No solution yet.

First: While building user controls frequently use Menu > Build > Clean up Project > Rebuild Project .. Cleans up akward Dependencies that have long gone. Otherwise it will even "correct" your code to wrong code.

"Object reference not set": Maybe for one of your controls your xaml namespace and/or classname doesn't match your code-behind-classname and namespace. It doesn't tell you that in detail. At least you know which one by its filename.

Repeat Frist.

Maybe this may solve you "compatibility"-issue, too.

Answer (score 1):

New blend for VS2015 is a big mistake. Crashes all the time. I create binding, open binding window choose a converter...crash. I move one object in designer...crash. I changed something in XAML...crash.. And this is normal work with new Blend solution.

Microsoft you're shooting yourselves in the foot...